# Calibracion cámaras ToF en C++ sobre Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cámara

Quiero calibrar una cámara con imágenes de chessboards desde una carpeta que se pueda elegir seleccionando el numero de imágenes y/o filtrando las mismas por algún carácter o tipo de imagen.

**Mi pregunta es:** No consigo que calibre la cámara ni por lo tanto que cree archivo con la matriz de calibración (me gustaría que este archivo tuviera un nombre a definir por una variable).

**Mi codigo hasta ahora**

Función para recoger las esquinas de la chessboard y crear matriz de calibración:

```
int CameraCalibrator::addChessboardPoints(const std::vector<Mat>& imageList, cv::Size & boardSize){
// points on the chessboard
vector<Point2f> imageCorners;
vector<Point3f> objectCorners;
// 3D Scene Points
// Initialize the chessboard corners in the chessboard reference frame.
// The corners are at 3D location (X,Y,Z)= (i,j,0)
for (int i=0; i<boardSize.height; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<boardSize.width; j++)
        objectCorners.push_back(Point3f(i, j, 0.0f));

// 2D Image Points
Mat image; // to contain the current chessboard image
int successes = 0;
// for all viewpoints
int listSize = (int) imageList.size();
for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++)
{
    // get the image in grayscale
    image = imageList[i];
    cvtColor(image, image,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    // get the chessboard corners
    findChessboardCorners(image, boardSize, imageCorners);
    // get subpixel accuracy on the corners
    cv::cornerSubPix(
                image,
                imageCorners,
                Size(5,5),
                Size(-1,-1),
                TermCriteria(
                    TermCriteria::MAX_ITER +
                    TermCriteria::EPS,
                    30,      // max number of iterations
                    0.1) //min accuracy
                );
    // if we have a good board, add it to our data
    if (imageCorners.size() == (unsigned int) boardSize.area()) {
        // add image and scene points from one view
        addPoints(imageCorners, objectCorners);
        successes++;
    }
}
return successes;}
```

Función con botón para comenzar búsqueda de imágenes y su lectura:

```
void CalibrationChess::on_ButtonCalibrate_clicked(){
QString folder;
QString w, h, n;
folder = ui->FolderInput->text();
if (folder.isNull() == true) return;
w = ui->NWidth->text();
if (w.isNull() == true) return;
h = ui->NHeight->text();
if (h.isNull() == true) return;
n = ui->NImages->text();
if (n.isNull() == true) return;

//dir = opendir(folder.c_str());int listSize = (int) dir;for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++)    {        imageList = dir[i];    }

QDir Directorio (folder);
QStringList filters;
filters << ui->lineExtension->text();
QFileInfoList fileImageList = Directorio.entryInfoList(filters, QDir::Files|QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);


for(int j=0; j<fileImageList.size(); j++)
{
    imageList[j] = imread(fileImageList.at(j).absoluteFilePath().toStdString());
}

boardSize.width = w.toInt();
boardSize.height = h.toInt();
numRequiredSnapshot = n.toInt();

ui->takeSnaphotButton->setEnabled(false);

// open chessboard images and extract corner points
successes = cameraCalib.addChessboardPoints(imageList,boardSize);

// calibrate the camera frames
Size calibSize = Size(ui->after_calib->size().width(), ui->after_calib->size().height());
cameraCalib.calibrate(calibSize);

isCalibrate = true;
ui->success_label->setText("Successful images used: " + QString::number(successes));

curFile = ui->FolderOutput->text();
QFile file (curFile);
if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
    ui->labelCamType->setText(file.fileName());
    file.fileName()+=".txt";
    QDataStream out(&file);
    out << cameraCalib.cameraMatrix.data;
    out << cameraCalib.distCoeffs.data;
    file.close();
}else{
    QMessageBox::warning(
                this,
                "Calibration Chessboard",
                tr("Cannot write file %1.\nError: %2")
                .arg(curFile)
                .arg(file.errorString()));
}}
```

Función de calibración:

```
double CameraCalibrator::calibrate(Size &imageSize)
{
    // undistorter must be reinitialized
    mustInitUndistort = true;
    //Output rotations and translations vectors
    vector<Mat> rvecs, tvecs;
    // start calibration (you can use solvePnP instead of calibrateCamera)
    return calibrateCamera(objectPoints, // the 3D points
                           imagePoints,  // the image points
                            imageSize,    // image size
                            cameraMatrix, // output camera matrix
                            distCoeffs,   // output distortion matrix
                            rvecs, tvecs, // Rs, Ts
                            flag);        // set options
}
```

Comment: No consigues que se calibre la cámara... ¿no puedes proporcionar más detalles al respecto? Se que la pregunta tiene ya 2 meses, ha pasado un tanto desapercibida